# Does a binary code with length 6, size 32 and distance 2 exist?

Tags: information-theory, coding-theory, encoding-scheme

The problem is to prove or disprove the existence of $C$, s.t., $|c| = 6,\forall c\in C$; $|C| = 32$; $d(c_i,c_j)\geq2,1\leq i<j\leq32$. ($d$ stands for hamming distance)

I tried to construct a satisfying code. The best I can get is to let $C = C'\times C'$, a concatenation of $C' = \{000,011,110,101\}$, which is of size 16. 32 happens to be the theoretical upper bound of the size, now I don't know what to do next so as to solve the problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, there is such a set. You are actually on the right track to find the following example.

Let $C = \{c : |c|=6 \text{ and there are even number of 1's in c}\}$. You can check the following.

- $|C|=32$.
- $d(u,v)\geq2$ for all $u,v\in C$, $u\not=v$. (In fact, $d(u,v)=2$ or 4 or 6.)

---

Here are four related exercise, listed in the order of increasing difficulty. As in the question, only binary code is concerned.

**Exercise 1.** Give another example of a set of 32 words of length 6 and pairwise distance at least 2.

**Exercise 2.** Show that there are only two such sets, as given in the answer and in the exercise 1.

**Exercise 3.** Generalize the above to words of any given length and pairwise distance at least 2. (Hint, $32=2^{6-1}$.)

**Exercise 4.** (further generalization stated in Yuval's answer) If $A(n,d)$ is the maximum size of a code of length $n$ and minimum pairwise distance $d$, then $A(d,2d)=A(n-1,2d-1)$.

Comment: I think $d(u,v)$ may also be 6, specifically for $u=000000$ and $v=111111$, as both $u\in C$ and $v\in C$ because both have even number of 1's. Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 7):

All words of even parity from a linear code with $2^{n-1}$ codewords and minimum distance $2$.

More generally, if $A_2(n,d)$ is the maximum size of a code of length $n$ and minimum distance $d$, then $A_2(n,2d) = A_2(n-1,2d-1)$.

Comment: Nice fact, upvoted. By the way, why not just $A(n,d)$ instead of $A_2(n,d)$? Oh, two letters.

Comment: The subscript signifies the field $\mathbb{F}_2$.